# Memory leak analysis of IAR workbench (EWARM)

Tags: c, memory-leaks, arm, valgrind, iar

I have recently bought IAR Workbench IDE for ARM (EWARM). My license does not include C-RUN to do memory leak check. Is it possible to use a 3rd party tool, like Valgrind to be able to perform a memory leak analysis?

Comment: [C-RUN](https://www.iar.com/iar-embedded-workbench/add-ons-and-integrations/runtime-analysis/)? (I haven't used it myself)

Comment: Are you sure you need this? When we have used low-end ARMs (<= Cortex-M3), we have usually disabled heap completely, and used stack/globals instead.

Comment: I couldn't find where is C-RUN on the IDE, I don't see any analysis option on the Tool or Project menus. I want to do similar analysis to Valgrind to see if there is any memory problem on the code. The license I have says I have C-RUN, but could not figure out how to use it

Comment: Actually C-RUN is not included on my license, I will update the question, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your program doesn't contain a standard-compliant `main` entry point, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to compile it without linking (eg. `gcc -c your_file.c`) and then link a standard-compliant `main` entry point to it that performs a series of tasks and exits as your program should... You could then run those testcases using valgrind on any PC that Valgrind will run on.

If there are platform-specific functions, well, most of the sane projects that I've ever seen/worked on have had some way to separate those into a platform-specific code while keeping the portable, standard-compliant code together (eg. in a `lib`). I hope for your sake that your program is developed with portability in mind, because it'll make such testcases easy to develop and run.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico I do try... Thanks for your compliment :)

Answer (score 0):

if your tools do not provide heap debugging features in their dynamic memory implementation, you could try to replace these with a library that does.

dmalloc (http://dmalloc.com) is a free library of such routines providing features like fencing dynamically allocated heap areas and observing freed block access.